# add html to xml properties file for email in java

Tags: java, spring

I want to send html email.I am using spring framework Mailsender class to send email and there is a email_en.xml file which contains the content which is something like

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
>    <!DOCTYPE properties [ 
> <!ELEMENT properties ( comment?, entry* ) >
> <!ATTLIST properties version CDATA #FIXED "1.0">
> <!ELEMENT comment (#PCDATA) >
> <!ELEMENT entry (#PCDATA) >
> <!ATTLIST entry key CDATA #REQUIRED>
>   ]>
>   <properties>
>  <entry key="subject">
>  email
> </entry>
>  <entry key="to">
>    test@test.com
>   </entry>
>   <entry key="name">
>        Garry
>     </entry>
>     <entry key="body">
>    Dear User,
>   <![CDATA[
>     Dear User,
>     <b>This is your email for reference</b>
> ```

```
    ]]>
    </entry>
    </properties>
```

So can I add html tags to this file I tried but it does not work. I have also added [CDATA[ ]] tag but it still not working.

Anyone can give me some idea

Comment: I do not understand clearly your question, are you trying to add body to your email in html format?

Comment: Yes Vyoma,  <entry key="body"> is already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are using just [MailSender](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/MailSender.html) and sending simple e-mail messages. In order to handle HTML content you should use [JavaMailSender](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSender.html) which offers you possibility to send [MimeMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html?is-external=true).

This [Spring e-mail tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.5/reference/mail.html) describes the differences, and how to correctly prepare e-mail messages (it's for version 2.x.x, but should be applicable to 3.x.x).

If you are using MimeMessageHelper, don't forget to set the [HTML flag](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#setText%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) to true when calling `#setText` method.

P.S. It seems that you are using your custom utility to parse XML messages and turn them into Message beans. Review your code and make sure that appropriate setters are called since properties in your XML message doesn't match property names in [MailMessage](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/MailMessage.html).